# ckeditor add text buttons

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying yo add text to the editor using some buttons,

So actualy I've done this :

the probelm is that i've done many scritps tryied in order to display the content of links to be displayed in the textarea something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:CKEDITOR.editor1.insertText( ' [CADRCOM2]' );" style="color:green;" title="Adresse Client 2e ligne">[CADRCOM]</a>
```

But nothing works.

to editor is good displaying but it doesn't work while adding text.

Anyone can help me please?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the sample pages provided with CKEditor? ckeditor/_samples/api.html has some sample text inserts.